# Rails: How do you access a scope from a returned object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In the following example, how can the `amount_below_limit` instance method access the argument to the `max_weight` scope?

```
# Model
class Elephant < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :max_weight, lambda { |limit| where('weight <= ?', limit) }

  def amount_below_limit
    max_weight = # How can I see 1000 from here?
    max_weight - weight
  end
end

# Controller
@elephants = Elephant.max_weight(1000)

# View
<% @elephants.each do |elephant| %>
  <%= elephant.amount_below_limit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I guess this should bot be theoretically possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions.

In the end, I refactored my code to make the parameter to `max_weight` an instance variable, which I then passed on to the `amount_below_weight` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in sql:

```
class Elephant < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :max_weight, lambda { |limit| where('weight <= ?', limit).
                                      select("elephants.*, #{limit}-weight as amount_below_limit") }
  def amount_below_limit
    read_attribute(:amount_below_limit) || -1
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly one solution, but I wanted to avoid using SQL `SELECT` if possible.

Comment: The limit should be stored separately in each instance rather than the class.  If you cache the variable in the class you run the risk of inconsistencies - for example, what if you make the call twice with two different limits?  I suggest you reconsider SQL + select.

Answer (score 0):

limit is scoped to the block.  it doesn't exist outside the lambda

Comment: Is it possible to access the query criteria from a result object?